# Why is this.props.username undefined in React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js, reselect

When I try to access `this.props.username` in:

```
loginClick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Login submit click, props.username: ' + this.props.username);
  this.props.loginDispatch(this.props.username);
}
```

I get undefined.
 Can you tell me what I'm missing?

**Reducer:**

```
    import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
    import { DEFAULT_ACTION, SET_USERNAME } from './constants';

    const initialStateMutable = {
      username: ''
    };

    const initialState = fromJS(initialStateMutable);

    function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case DEFAULT_ACTION:
          return state;
          case SET_USERNAME:
            console.log('reducer state.username value: ' + state.username);
              return {
              ...state,
                username: action.username
              };

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

**Action:**

```
    import { LOGIN_SUBMIT, SET_USERNAME } from './constants';

    export const loginDispatch = (name) => ({
      type: LOGIN_SUBMIT,
      name,
    });

    export const setUsername = (username) => {
      return {
        type: SET_USERNAME,
        username,
      };
    };
```

**Selector:**

```
    import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

    const selectLoginPageDomain = () => (state) => state.get('loginPage');

    const makeSelectLoginPage = () => createSelector(
      selectLoginPageDomain(),
      (substate) => substate.toJS()
    );

    export default makeSelectLoginPage;
    export {
      selectLoginPageDomain,
    };
```

**index.tsx:**

```
    import makeSelectLoginPage from './selector';
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { loginDispatch, setUsername } from './actions';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';


    interface ILoginProps {
      loginDispatch: Function;
      setUsername: Function;
      username: string;
    }

    interface ILoginState {
    }

    class LoginPage extends React.Component<ILoginProps, ILoginState> {
      constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
      }

      updateInputValue = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Current value of props.username: ' + this.props.username);
        this.props.setUsername(event.target.value);
      }

      loginClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Login submit click, props.username: ' + this.props.username);
        this.props.loginDispatch(this.props.username);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
           <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-inside">
                  <div className="alignc">
                    <form onSubmit={this.loginClick} className="row">
                      <div>
                        <div className="alignl">
                          Enter username for calculation history.
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <input type="text" value={this.props.username} onChange={this.updateInputValue}/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
      }
    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      ...state,
      username: state.username,
      ...makeSelectLoginPage()(state),
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      dispatch,
      setUsername: (value: string) => dispatch(setUsername(value)),
      loginDispatch: (name: string) => dispatch(loginDispatch(name)),
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

**UPDATE:**

I just realized I'm getting this error from the selector:
Uncaught TypeError: substate.toJS is not a function
    at eval (eval at ./app/containers/Login/selector.ts

Comment: I just realized I'm getting this error from my selector:

 Uncaught TypeError: substate.toJS is not a function
    at eval (eval at ./app/containers/Login/selector.ts (0.chunk.js:23), <anonymous>:13:21)

Answer (score 0):

`state` is an immutable variable. Try this :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state.toJS(),
  username: state.get('username'),
  ...makeSelectLoginPage()(state),
});
```

Comment: Accessing via `get` or directly won't make a difference here I think. It's quite common to access props from state in `mapStateToProps` like that. Unless it's a particular way of accessing props with `immutable.js`?

Comment: yes it is. Check the implementation of `makeSelectLoginPage`. `get` is used there to retrieve a key's value from `state`.